# Generic Class: UpdateView and DeleteView not saving data back to model

Tags: django, django-generic-views

The UpdateView and DeleteView not saving data back to model

views.py

```
class ProjectList(ListView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'mainapp/browse_app.html'
    context_object_name = 'projs'

class ProjectUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Project
    fields = ['pname','desc','emailID']
    template_name = 'mainapp/project_form_edit.html'

class ProjectDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Project
    fields = ['id','pname','desc','emailID','updated_on']
    template_name = 'mainapp/index.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('mainapp/projs')

def form_display(request):
    data = Project.objects.all()
    return render(request,'mainapp/browse_page.html',{'data':data})
...
```

browse_page.html: has an edit link and a delete button and it displays the project details of the project which is clicked

```
{% for i in data %}
    <center>
      <a href="#costumModal13{{ forloop.counter }}" role="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal">{{ i }}</a>
    </center>
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div id="costumModal13{{ forloop.counter }}" class="modal" data-easein="bounceLeftIn"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="costumModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <a class="btn btn-info btn-lg fa fa-pencil-square-o" href="{% url 'project_edit' pk=i.id %}" aria-hidden="true">Edit</a>
            <form method="POST" action="{% url 'project_del' pk=i.id %}">
                {% csrf_token %}<input type="submit" value="Delete">
            </form>
            {{ i.pname }}
            {{ i.id }}
            {{ i.updated_on }}
      </div>
{% endfor %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from mainapp import views
from mainapp.views import ProjectUpdate, ProjectDelete

app_name = 'mainapp'
urlpatterns = [
    path('browse/',views.form_display,name="browse_page"),
    re_path(r'^browse/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ProjectUpdate.as_view(), name='project_edit'),
    re_path(r'^browse/delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ProjectDelete.as_view(), name='project_del'),
]
```

[On submitting the edited form:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehJya.png)
[On clicking on delete button:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/el9z6.png)

Can you help me resolve these 2 errors?

Comment: The views you show here do not make much sense. You subclass from a `request`? You make `print` statements in the `class` scope?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry forgot to edit those out, was trying out a bunch of things and had to edit it to this small code snippet. How about now?

Answer (score 0):

**1st image problem:**

The url has index.html appended to the end. Your url is defined as `/browse/7/`

**2nd image problem:**

The namespace delimeter is `:` not `/`.

```
class ProjectDelete(DeleteView):
    ...
    success_url = reverse_lazy('mainapp:projs')
```

Comment: How do I remove the appended index.html from the end of the url? And for the second one, I haven't defined any namespace in my urls.py, should I add another path url, path('browse/delete/<pk>',include('app_name.view_name.urls',namespace="delete")). Won't it conflict with the already defined path?

Comment: I don't know. How are you generating the url? You have defined a namespace with the `app_name` property. And no, you shouldn't add another url path.